Survival analysis and censoring
I have conducted survival tests on C. elegans. I recorded dead and alive worms each day. The data mostly contains an unequal number of starting worms and also some missing worms (pretty normal in such a kind of experiment).
How do I censor my data? Should I write a for loop?
